# ggplot barplot - percentage on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

So, my dataset looks like this:

```
id  group   age length  Bnull_subject   Bnull_object    Bnull_other
1   NS  23  NA  3   3   1
2   NS  23  NA  1   4   0
3   NS  58  NA  4   4   1
4   NS  24  NA  2   3   1
5   NS  32  NA  3   2   0
6   NS  24  NA  4   1   1
7   NS  25  NA  5   2   0
8   NS  24  NA  3   2   0
9   NS  25  NA  3   2   0
22  ATT 26  [5-7]   4   4   0
23  ATT 28  [5-7]   4   1   0
24  ATT 28  [5-7]   5   3   1
25  ATT 28  [5-7]   1   5   1
26  ATT 26  [5-7]   4   2   0
27  ATT 29  [5-7]   3   2   0
```

I am trying to create a barplot with ggplot with persentage on the y axis but i cant get it to work correctly for some reason.. Here is the code i used

```
dset.bnull <- subset(dset, select = c(group, length, Bnull_subject, Bnull_object, Bnull_other))


    library(reshape2)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)
mdat <- melt(dset.bnull[c(1,3:5)], id.vars="group") #?melt <- Converts an object into a molten data frame

head(mdat) #Shows top observations of your data

ggplot(mdat, aes(variable, value, fill = group)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (value)/sum(value)), stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + #Use percentage on y axis
  xlab("Referent") + #Rename x axis
  ylab("Percentage of Answers") + #Rename y axis
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Experimental \nGroup"))
```

The plot I get is this... (it's wrong obviously)

[image]

Any help about what I should do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try placing the calculation (`y = (value)/sum(value))`) in the ggplot call: `ggplot(mdat, aes(x = variable, y = value / sum(value)), fill = group)) + ...` and remove it from the `geom_bar()` call.

Comment: @Phil I have already tried that and it didn't work...

Comment: Try calculating percentages before melting and use them as values for ggplot2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just got your `melt` wrong.

Try

```
mdat <- melt(dset.bnull[c(1:2, 5:7)], id.vars=c("id", "group"))
```

and remove

```
position=position_dodge(1)
```

from the `geom_bar` call.

---

Update: From your comment I'm guessing you're comfortable using `dplyr`. It'll be more intuitive to plot after summarising the data.

```
plot_data = mdat %>% group_by(group, variable) %>% summarise(total = sum(value))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(fill = group)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(x = variable, 
               y = (total)/sum(total)), 
               stat = "identity", 
               position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  xlab("Referent") + 
  ylab("Percentage of Answers") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Experimental \nGroup"))
```

Comment: my bad.. I forgot to say that i a subset dataset before that.. dset.bnull <- subset(dset, select = c(group, length, Bnull_subject, Bnull_object, Bnull_other))

Comment: It messes up the percentages because setting `position = "dodge"` overwrites the default `position = "stack"`, so all the bars are on top of each other (and you can only see the max in each group). Summarising the data gets rid of any tricky issues "dodge and stack" issues.

Comment: That worked, thank you! My head was so messed up I didn't think about using dplyr at all. Just to correct a minor thing.. after calling ggplot, you need a '+' not ','. Thanks again.